# Total Possible Outcomes For 7 Dice

Tags: statistics

6-sided dice
7 total dice

Key to this question - I am considering that order matters, so an outcome of 1,2,3,4,5,6,1 and 1,1,2,3,4,5,6 are different outcomes because their order is different.  How many total outcome possibilities are there for this?  And how did you get to that number?

Answer (score 2):

There are $6$ possibilities for he first dice, $6$ for the second, 6 for the third, etc. So the total number of possible outcomes is $6^7=279,936.$